# ADF 12.2.1.4 c DVT line chart Direction (Right to Left) Rendering

Tags: oracle-adf

There is any way to render DVT lineChart from Left to right even if my pege locale languge is 'ar' (Arabic) and trinidad-config.xml as in attached image???

please note that when the **right to left** is true the *Yaxis * be on right side
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0h5L.png)

LineChart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPEyM.png)

I have tried to sround the DVT line chart with Html DIV and set dir='ltr' but it dosent work